# Trying to make a Roster class out of a Player class (in Django), Help! This is for a class assignment

Tags: django, list, class, django-models

**Working on my models.py for my Team manager app and I can't figure out how to layout my class for a roster. I am new to Django so any help is greatly appreciated. The idea is to have the players on the team but then having a roster to show who is playing which game. Here's what I have so far:**

```
class Player(models.Model):
    player_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    cap_number = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        result = ''
        if self.cap_number == '':
            result = '%s, %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name)
        else:
            result = '%s, %s (%s)' % (self.last_name, self.first_name, self.cap_number)
        return result

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name', 'cap_number']
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['last_name', 'first_name', 'cap_number'],
                             name='unique_player')
        ]

class Roster(models.Model):
    roster_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    roster_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    player = models.ManyToManyField(Player)

    def __str__(self, data=None):
        return f'{self.roster_name} -  {self.player}'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['roster_name', 'player']
```

**And this is the error I get when I try to run makemigrations:**

ERRORS:
organizer.Roster: (models.E015) 'ordering' refers to the nonexistent field, related field, or lookup 'player'.

**Do I have to make another class to put the players into a list?**

Answer (score 0):

define the ordering based on any field of Player model.

you can do something like this for order by first name

```
ordering = ['roster_name', 'player__first_name']
```

Comment: But does that put a specified player into a roster?
I want different rosters for different games, with each roster consisting of various combinations of the players available.
I changed my code to this and it's not giving me an error but I don't think it's right still
    class Roster(models.Model):
    roster_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    roster_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)

    def __str__(self, data=None):
        return f'{self.roster_name} -  {self.players}'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['roster_name']